# A modern-C++-oriented testing framework for C++ code

Tags: software-development, c++, framework, software-testing

I've read

[C++ unit testing framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/c-unit-testing-framework)

which is closed as too broad; and answer-wise, while it lists several testing frameworks it doesn't really compare them or discuss their features.

Now, I'm interested in adding a framework for unit tests for an existing project of mine. It actually already includes a binary which performs a certain kind of unit tests, or perhaps I should something between unit and subsystem tests - but its' not a unit testing framework in itself and not intended to test all of the code. Which is why I want a proper framework. It may (or may not) also allow me to drop some of the custom code I have right now.

A significant requirement that I have is that the framework be **Modern-C++-oriented**. That is, that the syntax for using it will be C++11'ish (could be C++14 or C++17, but the latter option might give me some trouble due to CUDA compatibility issues), rather than just supporting the testing of C++11 code as an afterthought. So when I read, for example, that Google Test only needs a C++98 compiler, I get worried.

Other key features (partly adapted from [this article](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle)):

- Minimal amount of work needed to add new tests.
- Easy to modify and port - but **not** for the reasons mentioned [here](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle)! That is, it can and should depend on advanced C++ language and standard library features, as long as they're standard; and I don't mind dependencies on something like, say, CMake, or some scripting language etc, as long as it's tolerant to the difference between OSes and OS distributions.
- Supports setup/teardown steps (fixtures).
- Flexible and robust w.r.t. exceptions, crashes and asserts.
- Nice pretty-printed/ASCII-graphics-enhanced console output. I don't care for any specific such features, e.g. colors vs monochrome or whether or not progress and succeses/failures are animated, but it should be pleasingly readable.
- Integration with IDEs is a big plus

and of course:

- Free and Open Source license
- Gratis
- Support for different output formats, for use by various post-mortem tools

I would really like a comparison of strengths and weaknesses w.r.t. the features I listed as well as a comparison on a single framework.

Comment: What's wrong with https://github.com/google/googletest ?

Comment: @Mawg: Old, not utilizing C++11/14 features.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That will help others sot help you (+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### DocTest

[Presented in CppCon 2017 by Victor Kirilov](https://ru-clip.com/video/eH1CxEC29l8/cppcon-2017-viktor-kirilov-%E2%80%9Cmix-tests-and-production-code-with-doctest-%E2%80%9D.html)

This actively-developed framework is not actually modern-C++-targeted, but it's aiming to be with its next major release (2.0; it's at 1.2 right now).

- Motto: "The fastest feature-rich C++98/C++11 single-header testing framework for unit tests and TDD"
- Framework code: https://github.com/onqtam/doctest
- Ambitious [roadmap](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/roadmap.md), including IDE integrations
- Purportedly very fast - with [benchmarks] against the Catch framework (but I have no idea if Catch is faster than Gtest, CppUnit etc.)

Note: I haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Boost](http://www.boost.org) as a dependency, then [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) is a no-brainer choice. Consistent, feature-complete, as minimalistic or as rich as you need it to be.

Comment: Can you explain how it is oriented towards modern C++? I was under the impression it's a bit old.

Comment: @einpoklum - correct word is "mature", not "old". Why don't you point which aspect it is outdated in and we discuss?

Comment: I meant "old" as in "implemented in pre-2011 C++".

Comment: been testing C++1xyz code since time it was called C++0x (late 2010), never felt Boost.Test blocking me, you do want to build some project-specific test rigs library around it but that's about it - it does not force you to degrade the syntax ( or use boost::mpl and boost::fusion unnecessarily :-) )

Answer (score 0):

#### Bandit

"A human-friendly unit testing for C++11"

- Main website: http://banditcpp.org
- Framework code: https://github.com/banditcpp/bandit

Apparently, this framework "bends over backwards" to make your test's source code read like a natural-language description of a test. For example, here is a test of a guitar, which makes sure it sounds distorted in distortion mode:

```
describe("in distorted mode", [&]() {
    before_each([&]() { fuzzbox->flip(); });

    it("sounds distorted", [&]() {
        AssertThat(guitar->sound(), Equals(sounds::distorted));
    });
});
```

Note: I haven't tried this one myself.

Comment: a) Please do not recommend things you have not tried yourself. b) please do not suggest multiple tools in one answer.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: a) On what are you basing these suggestion? b) Do you mean to suggest using multiple answers instead?

Comment: One answer per tool: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/should-i-flag-answers-that-contain-multiple-independent-solutions and https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-to-do-when-an-answer-contains-several-suggestions/388#388

Comment: @ThomasWeller: a) No references for this yet... and I disagree. People can try out tools even without evaluations here on the site. b) So flag, don't downvote... anyway, split my answer.

Comment: Personal experience: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong

Comment: I can't flag: it's not spam, not rude, it is a (multi-)answer, and it's not moderator's task to split answers into pieces.

Comment: It's also interesting that you have had the original need for such a tool yourself and now you haven't tried the solution. Why not?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: My coding effort have been focused elsewhere; and tests can continue to be written without a proper framework as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### Mettle

A C++14-and-up framework!

- Main website: https://jimporter.github.io/mettle
- Framework code: https://github.com/jimporter/mettle

Example:

```
suite<> basic("a basic suite", [](auto &_) {
  _.test("a test", []() {
    expect(true, equal_to(true));
  });

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    _.test("test number " + std::to_string(i), [i]() {
      expect(i % 2, less(2));
    });
  }

  subsuite<>(_, "a subsuite", [](auto &_) {
    _.test("a sub-test", []() {
      expect(true, equal_to(true));
    });
  });
});
```

Note: I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

### lest

- Stated design goals: Modern and C++11-native, single-file, header-only, small size
- Framework code: https://github.com/martinmoene/lest
- Missing: Suites of tests, parameterised tests, templated tests, test data generators, built-in hamcrest matchers.

Example:

```
const lest::test specification[] =
{
    CASE( "Empty string has length zero (succeed)" )
    {
        EXPECT( 0 == string(  ).length() );
        EXPECT( 0 == string("").length() );    
   },
}
```

Note: I haven't tried it myself.